# LSTM Keras ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I keep getting this error in my LSTM layer.

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 3)
```

Why is the shape (None, 3), how do I fix this? Also how do you tell the size of arrays?
Here is my model's code:

```
class RNN():
    def __init__(self, data, labels):
        #get data for the model
        self.SAMPLEAMOUT = 5
        self.data = np.array(data)
        self.labels = labels
        print(self.data.shape)
        #initialize model
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(LSTM(3, input_shape=self.data.shape))
        self.model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
        self.model.compile(optimizer='adam',
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        accuracy=['accuracy', 'loss'])
```

Comment: lstm receives input in this format... (n_sample, time_seq, feature_dim)... what is your time_seq?

Comment: Whats a time_seq? Sorry, Im pretty new to LSTM

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
self.model.add(LSTM(3, input_shape=self.data.shape))
```

to:

```
self.model.add(LSTM(3, input_shape=self.data.shape[1:]))
```